# Using jQuery with Ember action handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I am trying to access jquery object ($) from inside a action handler in ember controller. But it says `$` is undefined.

**How do you get access to jQuery object from an action handler?**

Take this app for example:

```
<div id="main"></div>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <div id="scroll-div">
        <h1>Test Div</h1>

    </div>
    <a href="" {{action "findHeight"}}>Find height</a>
</script>
```

### JS

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    rootElement: '#main'
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        findHeight: function(){
            console.log(this.$('#scroll-div').height);
        }
    }
});
```

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sisir/5ammt2fv/

Comment: _`$ is undefined`_ means there is no jquery library referenced. as `$` is an alias for `jQuery`.

Comment: Did you try to use "jQuery" instead of "$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of  all it is not recommended to do dom operation in controller. The better approach can be you set target="view" and handle this action there. Then your code inside action will work fine. If you want to handle it in controller itself, then use this code snippet

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        findHeight: function(){
            alert($('#scroll-div').height());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to change:

```
findHeight: function(){
   console.log(this.$('#scroll-div').height);
}
```

as to this:

```
findHeight: function(){
   console.log($('#scroll-div').height());
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ammt2fv/1/)

---

At this line `console.log(this.$('#scroll-div').height);` in your code `$('#scroll-div').height` here `scroll-div` is an id and it should be only one in length because ids should be unique per element and to get the height of that div you should use `.height()` not just `.height`.

Comment: so, I guess the jquery object doesn't get passed to action handlers through `this` like we see on `didInsertElement`

Comment: @Sisir Yes i guess `this` refers to a dom node while `$('#scroll-div')` is a jquery object so that is some where could cause issues. I have not worked on ember js.